# object has no attribute python, spotify api

Tags: python, api, spotify

I am trying to code a little program which will add a random song to my Spotify queue

this is my code;

```
import json
import requests
from datetime import date
from refresh import Refresh
import random
import requests
import string
import urllib


class AddSongs(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.spotify_token = ""
        self.uri = ""

    def get_random_tracks(self):
        wildcard = f'%{random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)}%'
        query = urllib.parse.quote(wildcard)
        offset = random.randint(0, 2000)
        url = f"https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q={query}&offset={offset}&type=track&limit=1"
        response = requests.get(
            url,
            headers={
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": f"Bearer {self.spotify_token}"
            }
        )
        response_json = response.json()
        print(response)

        tracks = [
            track for track in response_json['tracks']['items']
        ]
        self.uri = response_json["tracks"]["items"][0]["uri"]
        


        
        print(f'Found {len(tracks)} tracks to add to your queue')

        
        
        return tracks
        return self.uri

        def add_tracks_to_queue(self,):

            print('adding to queue...')
            url =f"https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/queue?uri={self.uri}"
        response = requests.post(
            url,
            
            headers={
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": f"Bearer {self.api_token}"
            }
        )
        

        print(f"Added {track['name']} to your queue")

        def callrefresh(self):

            print("Refreshing token")

        refreshCaller = Refresh()

        self.spotify_token = refreshCaller.refresh()

        self.get_random_tracks()

        return response.ok 
a = AddSongs()
a. callrefresh()
```

this code is giving me the following traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shakabediako/Documents/free_streams/main.py", line 74, in <module>
    a. callrefresh()
AttributeError: 'AddSongs' object has no attribute 'callrefresh'
>>>
```

I have been trying to fix this without any success. I have little understanding of python classes and class attributes so i would really appreciate the help

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an indentation problem.

You want to define your functions callrefresh and add_tracks_to_queue within the scope of the class, but instead, you are defining them within the scope of your get_random_tracks function.

Python uses indentation to define object scope, so because the functions above are indented within get_random_tracks, they get interpreted in the context of that function, so they're not being added to the classes methods, and therefore can't be called.

Unindenting callrefresh and add_tracks_to_queue by one level should resolve the problem